# React drag Textbox anywhere in View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, textbox

I want to build an interactive Flowchart App. The basic structure is already done (just a lot of input fields), but now I want to implement the `function` of commenting the flowchart.

The User should be able to **drag a text box anywhere he wants on the screen** and the location of the text box should be saved.

I'm already using `React-dnd` but I don't think this library fits. Do you have any recommendations which `library or method` I could use for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't react-dnd work?

Comment: because i have to define the whole view as a target area